How to change PV storageClass of Strimzi kafka cluster
I am new at Strimzi and want to get some advice
We have kafka cluster in GKE. It is deployed with Strimzi and
we have it on all stands including prod env.
Our configuration of PVC that used by
kafka:
    template:
      pod:
    .....
    storage:
      type: jbod
      volumes:
      - id: 0
        type: persistent-claim
        size: {{ .Values.kafka.storageSize | quote }}
        deleteClaim: true

And storage that zookeeper is using:
zookeeper:
...
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: {{ .Values.zookeeper.storageSize | quote }}
      deleteClaim: true

With this configuration PVs are created with ReclaimPolicy: Delete, because it is default Storage Class and I need to change it to custom (with ReclaimPolicy: Retain)
And now i need to save all data in topics and change storageClass of both broker's and zookeeper's storages.
So my question is what should I do and in what order because if I just change the class through .spec.storage.class then PVC will be released and PV would be deleted.

You can't really change the storage class for existing volumes.
There are several options how to work around it for Kafka:

If you use JBOD storage (it looks like it), you can add a new disk with the new storage class, and then move all partition-replicas from the old disk to the new one and finally remove the old disk once it is empty. To move the data, you right now have to use the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh script.
If you use KafkaNodePool resources (and if you don't, you can migrate to node pools), you can create a new node pool with the new storage class and move all partition-replicas to it, and then remove the old node pool once empty. Here, you can use Cruise Control to move the partition-replicas, so it is a but easier.

For ZooKeeper, none of these are really possibly. There are only hacky ways how to change the storage type. But maybe you can use the KRaft-migration that you would anyway need to go through sooner or later as an opportunity to change the storage type.

Hey Jakub!
Thank you for your reply.
Could you please clarify the first option about choosing retain storage class with jbod additional disk. As I checked before we can’t choose storage class if we use jbod. (This field is not mentioned in documentation of jbod template)
And yes, we don’t use node pools :(

And what do you think about opportunity to deploy second cluster and migrate data with mirror maker 2? And make it main cluster after migration

The JBOD storage just means it is an array of one or more volumes of either ephemeral or persistent claim types. You can specify the storage class there for each of the persistent volumes.

Mirror Maker could be of course an option. But it is pretty complex to migrate from one cluster to another as you would need to migrate the applications etc.
